# Construction of models for true but unprovable formulas

Tags: lo.logic

Gödel's Completeness Theorem shows that first-order logic is (semantically) complete, namely, provability and validity coincide.

Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem shows that there are theories where certain true (in the intended interpretation) formulas are undecidable, and thus such theory is (syntactically) incomplete. So there must exist models of such a theory, where the aforementioned formula is false.

Are there systematic ways to construct such a model, given the theory and formula?

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion. Perhaps a better way to frame the question is: what are the/some known systematic ways to construct such a model, given the theory and formula?

Comment: This is hard to answer generally. One would need to know the motivation behind such a question to give an appropriate answer. We know such models always exist, but for strong enough theories, by Tennenbaum's theorem, we also know that we cannot really describe them in a precise (computable) way. Forcing could be one answer for set theory, similar constructions exists also for arithmetical theories - but really the model you get in the end is as difficult to understand as the depth of tools you used to obtain it.

Comment: If you know that your formula is not provable, your theory together with the negation of your formula is consistent and Henkin construction gives you a "kind of explicit" model of this theory as a term model. I am assuming that you are not interested in these models?

Comment: You may be interested in a result of Kripke: for any r.e. $\Sigma_1$-sound extension $\textsf{T}$ of Peano arithmetic, there exists an easily definable subring $R$ of the ring of primitive recursive functions such that for any non-principal ultrafilter $D$ on $\omega$, $R/D$ is a recursively saturated model of $\textsf{T}$. His proof is given on page 16 of my 1980 thesis, https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.10540.

Comment: @Burak I'm not entirely uninterested in those, but it certainly would be interesting to see others beyond the semantics-by-syntax ones that Henkin's construction might produce, which feel rather artificial.

Comment: What's wrong with: given a theory $T$ and an unprovable $\phi$, consider the model of $T + \neg \phi$ given by the construction in the usual proof of Gödel's completeness? Are we obsessing about syntacti things being less worthy? Or about the fact that the construction uses non-constructive principles?

Comment: @ale64bit, will you clarify in your question what sort of answers you would find natural, and what sort of answers you would accept?

Comment: Nothing wrong with syntactic models. I just wanted to know about other constructions as well, if any. I don't think I had in mind a particular notion of "naturalness" and that we are obsessing about syntacti things being less worthy; syntax is, after all, natural in its own domain. My question was meant to understand the different means available to construct such models, to get a grasp of the big picture. So I will accept any answer that provides such information. I'll edit the question to hopefully reflect this better.

Comment: A non-specialist speaking (sorry). I suggest to have look at Visser's "[The Interpretability of Inconsistency](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/handle/1874/288574)" (a 2014 preprint). He gives a readable exposition of Feferman's results from 1960. Quoting from the introduction: "... a theory interprets
itself plus its own inconsistency. In terms of models this tells us that there is a
uniform construction (of a special kind) that yields, for every model of the given
theory, an internal model of the theory that satisfies the formalized inconsistency
statement of the theory."

Comment: I think you have a somewhat unreasonable expectations. If you really want something that works for all theories $T$ and formulas $\phi$, the *syntactic* fact that $T\nvdash\phi$ is the only thing you can work with. Thus, you cannot expect there to be a method that does not essentially build on syntax.

Comment: Fair enough then. Thanks everyone. @Burak feel free to post your comment as answer and I'll accept it. Or anyone else, really.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check out the Paris-Harrington theorem's use of indicators as one way to do this for a specific kind of Ramsey theorish combinatorial claim.  It's kinda a tough slog but it's a really explicit construction of a model of PA which makes a true (in N) combinatorial claim false.

Generally speaking, however, there is no general constructive method to produce such models.  However, I believe the indicator method from the Paris-Harrington theorem can be extended to work for cases where the issue is the provable totality of functions with a certain rate of growth.